# CakePHP 3 - Match results only for a specific where condition

Tags: mysql, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

Im having trouble to build a query using the cakePHP 3 ORM that selects all the posts where `'Posts.source' = 'app'` or all the posts where `'Posts.source' = 'twitter'`, but when the source is `'twitter'` the results should get matched with `$hashtags`;

I only get this to work where it matches all results to `$hashtags`.
This is what I have so far:

```
$postsTable = TableRegistry::get('Posts')
  ->find()
  ->where([
    'Posts.deleted' => 0,
    'Posts.source' => 'app'
  ])
  ->orWhere([
    'Posts.deleted' => 0,
    'Posts.source' => 'twitter'
  ])
  ->matching('PostHashtags', function ($q) use ($hashtags) {
    return $q->where([
      'PostHashtags.hashtag_id IN' => $hashtags
    ]);
  })
  ->all();
```

Now the query selects all not deleted posts from the source `'app'` plus all not deleted posts from the source `'twitter'` and matches all results to `$hashtags`.

But I only need the `"orWhere"` results to be matched with `$hashtags` as the results from the source `'app'` don't have any hashtags at all, they should be included no matter what.

Unfortunately I need this in one query, as I later will combine this with limits and offsets.

Is there any way to tell the query it should only match the data given in the `orWhere()` condition?

Comment: You are going to need to place the hashtag matching inside the orWhere statement. As is, the matching is applying to the overall query.

Comment: How is that possible, is there a special way to write an orWhere, as I normally just pass an array into it.

Comment: Since `matching` operate a join I don't think you can condition the join. Otherwise try to write down your desired query in plain sql and then we can help you translate into cake syntax. But I'd rather use a subquery instead of a join in this case